# C# Move Windows In Sync

Tags: c#

I have one simple C# application which opens another process. What I want is to move the Main Window of that opened process as I move the C# application. By now, what I have is this code:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);
```

It works to move the Window of the Process, but how do I get the event to move both windows in sync, so one moves as the other moves?

Comment: There is no easy way to receive notifications when *another process's* window is moved. If you control that other process, add code to notify your application when its window is moved. Otherwise, you'll need a hook, which cannot be written in C#. You *might* be able to use WinEvents for this, which is slightly more accessible to managed languages.

Comment: @CodyGray I think you understood my question upside down. My question is, I want to move the opened process as I move my own C# application.

Comment: Well, that would be part 1 of your question. But you said you want to "move both windows in sync", so part 2 would be moving the C# application's window when the other process's window moves. Part 2 is the hard part.

Comment: Are you trying to move the two windows in sync e.g side-by-side, or make the window appear to be a child window of the parent process? You could change the parent window using SetParent if you want to make the child window move as a child of your parent. If you want to simply make the windows move together, I would suggest moving the other window in the Move event as Drew McGowen suggest or override the WndProc method and move the other window when SC_MOVE messages are received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to move your other form when the C# form moves, which you can detect by adding a handler for the [`Control.Move`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.move(v=vs.110).aspx) event:

```
private void ControlMovedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MoveWindow(otherWindowHandle, Location.X, Location.Y, ...);
}
```

You can use the form editor to automatically add the event handler to the main form.

---

As far as getting *your* window to move when the *other* one does, it's much more difficult; one way would be to have a timer/loop constantly check to see if the other window's position changed, then move yourself accordingly. Also, you need to be careful that you don't get stuck in an infinite loop of moving the windows to the same location (i.e. A moves, which moves B, which then tries to move A, which then tries to move B, etc).

Comment: This answer works OK. This is what I wanted. Thank you.